# Svelte as a product name, are there any similar sounding negative words in other languages?

Tags: phonetics, multilingualism

We have decided to call our product "svelte", we want to sell it worldwide. We want to make sure that other languages don't have a similar sounding word with a bad connotation.
(I am not a linguistic professional.)

- I ran a search on google translate and got a few results. (this is very rough)

Icelandic - svelt - to starve,
Slowenian - svet - world / holy,
Aafrikans - swel - swell,
Western Frisian - swelt - swing,
Russian - svel - reduced,

- Is there something like an online phonetic dictionary, where it would show me similar sounding words in other languages?
- Or any other tips?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! I think this is an interesting question, but the last point asking for "any other tips" makes it a bit broad, which is not good for Stack Exchange network. In other words, an open set of interpretations leads to an infinite number of possible answers. Can we leave only the "phonetic dictionary" part of the question? Note that if you have other concerns in mind, it is always possible to ask it separately.

Comment: I am afraid, that just as in the case of identification of language fragments or translation of texts, this question and its potential answer are of no additional use for other visitors of this site. I therefore cast a close vote.

Comment: @bytebuster Yes if there was something like a "phonetic dictionary" that would be of help! i understand "any other tips" was a too broad question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no. You would first need a massively-multilingual dictionary which really covers *all* of the words in each language, and there isn't such a thing. You can always decide, at your peril, to ignore some languages. Then you would have to determine what would constitute "close enough", for example is "vitu" close enough to something in Finnish, or "pool" close enough to something in Norwegian. You can't just use pronunciation, so you would want to not use the Somali word for "food". Finally you would need the dictionary to be well-annotated for cultural information, which would indicate the additional nuances of *hooyada* (lit. "your mother") which are not found in *aabaha* ("your father").

Answer (score 1):

A couple more languages come to mind offhand:
Italian: svelto = quick, brisk, fast, slender etc
hence Modern Greek σβέλτος = quick, swift, lively, nimble etc

As for 'other tips', consider the spelling (the -e ending makes me think of French, and feminine, e.g. blond/blonde, fianc'e/fianc'ee).  Also vet the visual appearance of the font you will use for this, make sure that it doesn't look like a potentially undesirable letter or symbol in another alphabet.
HTH